# Can't get enemy to disappear upon collision

Tags: sprite-kit

I have been trying all my resources and thanks to my dear friend Sangon, a member here and the IOS Games by tutorial book from Ray Wenderlich and what I am trying to do is to first of all set categories for each node and then if my player's bullet gets collided with the enemy, I want the enemy to disappear. Now I got some suggestions where to start from but this thing is driving me nuts I have tried and tried and the enemy does not disappear. Please help me on this. thanks.

```
static const uint32_t EnemyCategory        = 1;
static const uint32_t bulletCategory       = 2;

- (void) fire:(float)targetAngle {
         bullet = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"cannonbullet"];
         bullet.position = _Player.position;
         bullet.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody 
                              bodyWithCircleOfRadius:bullet.frame.size.width/2];
         bullet.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = bulletCategory;
         bullet.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = bulletCategory | EnemyCategory;
         bullet.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = bulletCategory | EnemyCategory;
         [self addChild:bullet];
         int x = _Player.position.x + 1000 * cos(targetAngle);
         int y = _Player.position.y + 1000 * sin(targetAngle);
         [bullet runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(x, y) duration:2]];
}

- (void) didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
         SKPhysicsBody *temp;
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) {
         temp = contact.bodyB;
    } else {
         temp = contact.bodyA;
    }
    if (temp.categoryBitMask == EnemyCategory) {
        [temp.node removeFromParent];
    }
}


- (void) Enemy:(CGSize)size  {   
     Enemy = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"enemy1@2x"];
     Enemy.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
     Enemy.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:Enemy.frame.size];
     Enemy.physicsBody.dynamic =  NO;
     Enemy.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = EnemyCategory;
     [self addChild:Enemy];
}
```

Comment: did you set the scene as the physicsWorld delegate? Does didBeginContact run?

Comment: As Ray suggests you first need to make sure didBeginContact is called. Once that's getting called it's just a question of checking your bit masks, acting on the collision and removing one or both of the colliding sprites.

Comment: yes bud but how do I call the didBeginMethod? I tried to call it in the initWithSize main method but I get all kinds of errors. I mean can you please give me a hint for learning purposes that how would I call this method? I know how to call methods but this one is a little tricky.

Comment: Hi Ray. Did you ever get your issue solved?

Comment: to some degree yes because I used the debug draw from Ray's tutorial and it seems like the square collision zone wasn't big enough for the ball's collision but however, still sometimes at first start up, there is a glitch of delay start and also not every point with the enemy is colidable.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem that I can see is that you didn't set the `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` delegate properly

You will have to do something like this:

```
@interface MyScene : SKScene<SKPhysicsContactDelegate>
```

Once you do that you will also have to set the scene as the contactDelegate. It would look something like this:

```
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
```

And after this is done your scene will receive the `didBeginContact:` and `didEndContact:` messages *automatically*. Those methods are not something that you call *manually*.

[Here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-an-airplane-game-with-sprite-kit-explosions-clouds--mobile-19933) you can find a tutorial that uses collision detection (and removes the objects after collision detection)

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsContactDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013035-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1) ’SKPhysicsContactDelegate’

> An object that implements the SKPhysicsContactDelegate protocol can respond when two physics bodies are in contact with each other in a physics world. To receive contact messages, you set the contactDelegate property of a SKPhysicsWorld object. The delegate is called when a contact starts or ends.

Hope this helps